# How to parse "less than 60% based a turnout less than 75% "

Tags: prepositions, parsing

I've been struggling to parse the following sentence from the [UK petition to implement EU Referendum Rules triggering a 2nd EU Referendum](https://petition.parliament.uk/petitions/131215).

> We the undersigned call upon HM Government to implement a rule that if the remain or leave vote is less than 60% based a turnout less than 75% there should be another referendum.

I'm puzzled at the phrase "less than 60% based a turnout less than 75%". If it were something like "less than 60% based *on* a turnout *of* less than 75%",  I wouldn't have any trouble, but apparently it isn't. Especially the usage of "based" like this, without any preposition, seems quite unfamiliar.

How should I parse and understand the sentence?

Comment: As an AmE user, I would think it should be based "on". But it is possible that BrE users have a peculiar way of using _**a**_ that AmE users do not. I doubt it, but I would like to see what they say.

Comment: It amuses me that four million people have signed a petition the text of which is incoherent.

Comment: "based [on] a turnout less than 75%" http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-eu-referendum-36634407

Comment: @probablyme: Nope, just a typo. I remember seeing this a while ago — knew from HNQ immediately what the question referred to!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see. Yeah, the only reason I was suspicious was because it is a **petition to parliament** of all things. You would think that they'd be very careful about typos, but it happens I guess. I am assuming that can't go back in and fix it, otherwise wow. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @probablyme: A petition to parliament written by some randomer on the internet :) It has all the editorial oversight (formal or otherwise) of a Facebook status

Comment: @ColonelPanic Maybe that means that four million Brits were able, like ourselves, to work out that the word "on" was missing, thereby rendering the text coherent, see the value in the proposal, and add themselves to the petition.

Comment: An obvious error should not be pointed out as improper grammar. Dozens of 'errors' like the above can be seen every day in the newspapers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact it needs to read "based on" (or "based upon"; see comments).

As you indicated that you expected, *base on* is a phrasal verb here. It is a multi-word item which has a meaning like *using* in *X is calculated using Y.* It cannot retain this meaning if the *on* element is omitted. It's obviously a typo.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/base-on

It would also be more common in standard English to include *of* in *a turnout of less than 75%.* However, leaving it out is acceptable. In this case, *of* is a word, a preposition, that stands on its own. It is not so tightly attached to another word like *on* is to *based* in *based on.* It would be understood that *a turnout less than 75%* equals *a turnout [that is] less than 75%* or *a turnout [of] less than 75%.*

We can see that *on* has been added to the text [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/06/28/petition-for-second-eu-referendum-hits-4-million-as-hundreds-att/) and, [here](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/brexit-petition-for-second-eu-referendum-so-popular-the-government-sites-crashing-a7099996.html), and [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-eu-referendum-36629324).

Comment: Can you maybe add an explanation to this?

Comment: Like, We don't use *based* that way without *on?*

Comment: Simply adding 'on' doesn't make the sentence any easier to understand, especially for a learner..

Comment: The OP indicates that they would understand it with the missing on. I am answering that the on is required.

Comment: @Chenmunka - As for the meaning of _if the vote is less than 60% based on a turnout less than 75% there should be another referendum_ – say 59% vote to approve, and only 74% of the voters bothered to vote. If that happens, vote again. That's all it's saying.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Especially your comments on the *of* and the examples where *on* had been added, they made everything quite clear.

Comment: I would use "upon", but that may be just my middle-aged BrE.

Comment: @Klors Ah, I had not considered *upon.* I don't think it's any more *correct,* but perhaps more precise and more formal. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: looks like I'm in the minority anyway, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=based+upon%2Cbased+on&year_start=1900&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbased%20upon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbased%20on%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 14):

I am a British English speaker.

I think the person who posted the online petition just accidentally made some grammar mistakes because they created a petition in a hurry, and the website offered no feature to correct the grammar later.
The petition was posted very shortly before the final result of the voting was announced.  Perhaps the poster thought that, by posting before the final result, the petition had a greater chance of being accepted.  That was perhaps why they hurried and didn't check their grammar.

The correct usage should have been:
based [on] a turnout [of] less than 75%

The [on] is absolutely essential.  The [of] is optional, but usual usage.